# Flex Spark DropDownList - Add separator between item

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4

I am trying to create a dropdown that can display both past state and possible state for a customer.

But I want to make add a separator between past and possible state.

Actually to do that I add an item like "-----" on the dataprovider.

But the look and feel is not good and this item may be selected.

My ideal approach is something like that:

So how to do better?

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like you've already accomplished this, but are unhappy with the visual results.  If that is the case, how about you share what you've done via code and/or a screenshots.  Also tell us what your 'ideal' approach would be.  Then we can offer suggestions.

Comment: I +1 your edit because it explains what you tried to do; and what you'd like to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to create a custom skin for the `DropDownList`.

I have never skinned that component so I can not give you more details but if you are using Flash Builder, it is very easy to create new skins for a component: Just click the icon with a brush and a gear to the right of the "Skin" selector and choose *Create Skin*. Then, you can customize everything about how the component looks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a custom skin to the DropDownList is not the solution.  The drop down list is displayed with a DataGroup.  How would you shove an "Extra line" inside the DataGroup without having an item in the itemRenderer?  I think a custom itemRenderer that conditionally includes the line as part of the renderer would be the way to go.

Comment: @flextras - +1 You should use a custom ItemRenderer. You could also set the gap of the vertical layout and let the list background create a line between items.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a custom ItemRenderer. On the last item you could hide the line. However with this code you'll receive a data binding warning that the owner is not bindable.

```
<s:itemRenderer>
    <fx:Component>
        <s:ItemRenderer width="100%" height="100%" 
                        autoDrawBackground="true">
            <fx:Script>
                <![CDATA[
                    import spark.components.supportClasses.ListBase;
                ]]>
            </fx:Script>
            <s:states>
                <s:State name="normal"/>
                <s:State name="down"/>
                <s:State name="hovered"/>
                <s:State name="selected"/>
                <s:State name="dragging"/>
                <s:State name="normalAndShowCaret"/>
                <s:State name="hoveredAndShowCaret"/>
                <s:State name="selectedAndShowCaret"/>
            </s:states>


            <s:Line width="100%" top="2" visible="{itemIndex==outerDocument.lengthOfFirstItems-1}">
                <s:stroke>
                    <s:SolidColorStroke weight="1" caps="square"/>
                </s:stroke>
            </s:Line>

            <s:Group top="8" left="2" right="2" bottom="2" width="100%" height="100%">
                <s:Label id="labelDisplay" verticalCenter="1" horizontalCenter="0" />
            </s:Group>
        </s:ItemRenderer>
    </fx:Component>
</s:itemRenderer>
```

In your document create a variable called lengthOfFirstItems of type int. I assume you have two arrays? One for the top items and one for the bottom? If so then add the second array to the first (or create a third with all of them). Before joining your arrays set lengthOfFirstItems to the length of the first set of items. So using the image an example that length would be 2 since there are two items, your line, then the rest of the items.

```
// position of end of first array. must be public to be accessible by outerDocument
public var lengthOfFirstItems:int = -1;

// get length of first array
lengthOfFirstItems = firstArray.length;
```

With this example the line will be visible in the last row of the first array of items. You will probably have to adjust the code since part of it is pseudo code.

Comment: Thanks for helping but with you sample a line is adding between each item. Or in my case I'd like to split in two part dropdowlist.